# programmatic access to "ip route show"

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking

Is there a way to access information available in

```
ip route show
```

command via some special file (or other method), the same way that output of

```
route -n
```

can be read from /proc/net/route? I know that I can just parse the output, but I am looking for something in more machine-readable format.

Answer (score 3):

More recent versions of iproute2 support the `-j` argument that formats the output as JSON. Then you can extract the relevant data not with sed or awk, but with the `jq` tool.

```
$ ip route show dev eno1
default via 192.168.1.1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.5 metric 1002
192.168.1.0/24 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.5 metric 1002

$ ip -j route show dev eno1 | jq -r '.[].dst'
default
192.168.1.0/24
```

If you need it to be more machine readable than that (e.g. no `default`, no optional keys, separate netmask and destination), you might as well read from `/proc/net/route` directly, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

strace shows ip route show creating a NETLINK_ROUTE socket to get that: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html

Answer (score 1):

Same information is on "/proc/net/route". You could check that file, instead of capture standar output information from "netstat -n" command.

Answer (score 0):

What specific information are you trying to get?

This is the perfect thing to use either cut, awk to pull the specific fields you want out of it.

Example:

```
ip route show |  awk '{print $1 " " $9 }'
```

Returns network subnet and source IP.